# Finding a formula to calculate the final grade acquired.

Tags: average, percentages

the question is as follows.

Assume a student has got 4 assignments that will determine their final grade. Note, the grade ranges from 6-10. Assignment 'A' accounts for 15% of their final grade, 'B' accounts for 15%, C for 30% and D for 40%.

Am I wrong to assume that the students final grade would equate to:
$\dfrac{15x+15y+30z+40w}{100}=F$ where $F$ is the final grade and {x,y,z,w} is their respective grades in {A,B,C,D}.

For example, if the student for the following results:
A: 6
B: 10
C: 7
D: 10

Their final grade would be:

$\dfrac{15(6)+15(10)+30(7)+40(10)}{100}=\dfrac{17}{2}=8.5$

Comment: I find it strange that the lowest score you can make on an assignment is a "6"; but, if on any assignment, a "10" is perfect and a "6" gets you 60$\%$ of the assignment's total worth (and linear in between), then, yes, that is correct.

Comment: The same wording may represent a different situation where all of the four exams $A, B, C, D$ are graded $0\%-100\%$ and then you calculate $15A+15B+30C+40D$ and *only then* the grades $6-10$ are given ($6$ is between $50\%$ and $60\%$; $7$ is between $60\%$ and $70\%$ ... $10$ is between $90\%$ and $100\%$ while $<50\%$ means "fail"...